# DIV animation issue (x2)

Tags: jquery, animation

A two part question :)

I have a DIV set up (named two) outside of another DIV (named one). When I hover over "one" I want "two" to slide across into it. This works using the code below

```
    $(function(){ 
$(".one").mouseover(function(){
    $(".two").animate({left:-0}, 100);
});
});
```

When I use the same code but reverse the animation using "mouseout" it flickers twice on both the in and out animations. How can this be fixed?

```
    $(function(){ 
$(".one").mouseout(function(){
    $(".two").animate({left:-120}, 100);
});
});
```

The second part of the question is how can I set this up for multiple instances on the same page without having to create unique code and DIV names each time.

Comment: Can you please setup a http://jsfiddle.net demo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid having multiple animations run, you should [stop()](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) the element before calling a new `animate()`

```
$(function(){ 
    $(".one").mouseout(function(){
        $(".two").stop(true, true).animate({left:-120}, 100);
    });
});
```

Look at the docs about `stop` if you want to jump at the end or start from where it stopped.

For having multiple instances, you should do a jQuery plugin instead. If the second div is directly in the first one, and there is no other div, you can then call your plugin like :

```
$('div.your_div_parent').doMyFunc();
```

And in your function, you'll add the event on the `$(this, '>div');`

I can't be more precise because I lack some of your code and I'm not sure about what you exactly want about your last point.